# Как в opencart 3 вывести похожие товары?

Tags: opencart, opencart3.x

В opencart 3 стояла задача вывести товары из этой же коллекции, решил вопрос так:

в **product.php** добавил новый массив данных и его обработку путем копирования полного кода, отвечающего за вывод товаров в карточке `$data['products'] = array();` Единственное что изменил - это добавил поле `['mpn']` `(manufacturer number)`, которое используется в админке для указания названия коллекции.

Ну и в twig вывел эти товары, но только те, которые имеют название коллекции, идентичное названию коллекции с текущим просматриваемым товаром. Это было легко.

Но теперь хочу по этому же принципу вывести "похожие товары". Чем не подходит модуль из коробки? Тем, что "рекомендуемые товары" выводятся с заранее вручную установленными товарами. И что для каждого товара в админке добавлять похожие товары при создании нового товара? В моем случае это неудобно, всвязи с большим количеством товаров в магазине.

Вывести эти похожие товары по принципу "коллекций" не вопрос, единственное что я не понял пока, как сделать вывод именно **похожих** товаров, например я нахожусь в карточке "кресло 1" и тут мне надо чтобы выводились товары типа "кресло 2", "кресло 3" и так далее... **Как мне можно научить opencart в контроллере понимать какие товары считать похожими?**

Comment: определите похожие свойства "похожих" товаров и составьте соответсвующий запрос (в моделе) на выборку. я бы использовал теги

Comment: @Kirill, можно как-то подробнее? Понял, что что туповат в работе с базой, вот есть у меня в controller обращение к ф-ии в model, в model нужно написать ф-ию с выборкой товаров из базы, наверное из oc_product_description, SELECT FROM DBPREFIX pd WHERE pd.name LIKE "и тут как-то передать похожее имя товара"